# Dynamically created RSS Feed - some clients can not read content

Tags: php, symfony, dom, rss, silex

Using Silex and DOM I create a dynamically RSS Feed. The feed validate with the W3C Feed Validator without any errors - and can be read i.e. with Feedly without any problems. But I can not open the feed with the Internet Explorer or with Outlook - both prompt that the connection is lost while reading the RSS feed. If I save the feed without any changes as *.xml file IE & Outlook can process the feed, but this is not a intended solution, the feed should be dynamically.

The header of the RSS Feed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <channel>
    <atom:link href="https://.../rss/flexcontent" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
      ...
  </channel>
</rss>
```

In the Silex application the above generated XML is returned with:

```
return new Response($xml, 201, array('Content-Type' => 'application/xml'));
```

Should I use another response or is there anything else what is missing or perhaps wrong?

**Update - Solution**

The response should not send an (additional) Content-Type, this response works fine:

```
return new Response($xml, 201);
```

Comment: 201? Seems weird to me, there's no new resource created. A simple 200 would be better.

Comment: 201 stay for a created resource and the feed is just created so I take this response from [HTTP/1.1 Status Code Definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) - but at least I'm not shure which response is the correct one.